# Compilation failed for package ... from GitHub

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am trying to install a package from GitHub using `devtools`.

```
library("devtools")
install_github("tchakravarty/DCS")
```

but it gives me the following:

```
Downloading GitHub repo tchakravarty/DCS@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/tchakravarty/DCS/zipball/master
Installing DCS
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Alex S/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0gaVCB/devtools1790c6de55/tchakravarty-DCS-bcb00ac"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'DCS' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/RBUILD~1/3.4/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c GaussianCopulaGASModel.cpp -o GaussianCopulaGASModel.o
C:/RBUILD~1/3.4/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c MarkedPointProcess.cpp -o MarkedPointProcess.o
MarkedPointProcess.cpp:14:1: error: 'arma' does not name a type
 arma::vec SimulateMarkedPointProcess(arma::vec vEta, arma::mat mAlpha, arma::vec vOmega, 
 ^
make: *** [MarkedPointProcess.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="DCS.dll" OBJECTS="GaussianCopulaGASModel.o MarkedPointProcess.o RcppExports.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'DCS'
* removing 'C:/Users/Alex S/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/DCS'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Initially I thought it could be that I have different versions of R and Rtools so I made sure that I have latest versions of both (also updated R studio).
Also tried installing a different package from GitHub

```
install_github("kbroman/broman")
```

works just fine. Any ideas why? Can it be that the package I am failing to install from GitHub is outdated? 
Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: There seem to be a problem with the package itself. Since the last commit was three years old, it might be due to back tracked dependencies in older versions. My best guess would be to contact the package author.

Comment: @ThomasGuillerme, thanks for the comment ... contacted the author, while  waiting for the reply wrote my own function to perform operation that was specified in the package, I guess that it is how it works with programming :)) May be will post an answer with my function when my script is polished.